# Hartl Tutorial Chapter 13.1.3 User/Micropost associations: Why use create instead of create with a bang that raises exceptions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, railstutorial.org

In [Michael Hartl's rails tutorial chapter 13.3.1](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/user_microposts#sec-user_micropost_associations), we create a twitter-style micropost like this:

```
Micropost.create
```

My question is why use `Micropost.create` and not `Micropost.create!`?

It seems that you would always want to raise exceptions in active record if there's a problem so that you can address the exceptions.

Why would want to ever use `Micropost.create`? He explains that both are options with this table:
[image]

But he doesn't really explain why you would choose one or the other. So, why would you choose one over the other?

Comment: Is there a particular statement that the tutorial makes on this? Or is it a general question you have? (asking for context purposes) -- really good question too btw!

Comment: Just a general question. He explains that both `create` and `create!` are options, but doesn't explain why we are choosing `create`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it depends where you are using the method.

#### When to use `create`

If it's a simple create in your controller, generally you will use `create` to be able to control the flow logic, take this example:

```
if Micropost.create(micropost_params)
  # handle success save, e.g.:
  redirect_to :index
else
  # handle failure in save, e.g.:
  render :new
end
```

With the above code you *control the flow **without** using exceptions*, and that's what you want when you create a record: Handle errors that you know that will be likely to happen without raising exceptions.

So, i prefer to ask it the other way around: why use `create!` and raise an exception (and get the related overhead) if you could just get a `false` and handle the error? And why do it if i need more code to handle that exception?

While this is a valid use `create`, it's not that common, since `save` and `update` are more likely to be used (in most cases you will create using `new` and then saving with `save`).

#### When to use `create!`

If you want to update multiple records within the same action (read [transactions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html)), then `create!` will serve you better; consider the following example:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  user1.update!(balance: user1.balance + 100)
  user2.update!(balance: user2.balance - 100)
  transfer.create!(amount: 100, receiver: user1, sender: user2)
end
```

Here you update 2 records and create 1 within the same transaction, but if one of them fails you need to do a rollback to keep you data integrity intact. So, if you use `create` you will need to handle the rollback yourself to undo the transaction; on the other hand, using `create!` will raise an exception that triggers the rollback automatically.

Another good use for `create!` is *testing* (as in Hartl's tutorial) and *debugging*, i found them more convenient since they help catch errors a lot faster.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. So, now I guess my question would be why would you ever use `create!`?

Comment: @LeeMcAlilly I updated the answer, i hope this helps you better understand the use between the two.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't completely in the dark if a `create` fails.

```
my_micropost = Micropost.create

if my_micropost.persisted?
  puts "successfully saved"
else
  puts "something went wrong"
end
```

It gives you a simple mechanism to handle the failure condition. You can reference `my_micropost.errors` to determine what the issue was and handle accordingly, for example.

Whereas to recover from `create!` without exposing the exception to the end user means you'll need to rescue from the raised exception, which is a more complex process.

Comment: Ok. makes perfect sense now. So I guess now my question is the opposite. Why would you ever use `create!`?

Comment: @LeeMcAlilly I've used it in the `seeds` file or in tests so that an exception is thrown early and I know I need to investigate.

Comment: As @GavinMiller says.  If there's no legitimate business reason for a record to fail creation then you can use `create!` to trap the error you don't otherwise expect or planned to handle.